# Is it possible to return the time the daily high was made? (pinescript)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

So I’m basically building a custom indicator and trying to retrieve the time the previous daily high was made.

I’m using:

```
PDH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, ‘D’, high[1])
```

To retrieve the previous daily high price but is it possible to retrieve the time the high was made?

Would greatly appreciate any help with this, been bugging me for hours!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below [function](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-convert-a-time-to-a-date-time-string) to convert `time` to a date-time string.

```
f_timeToString(_t) =>
      str.tostring(year(_t), "0000") + "." + str.tostring(month(_t), "00") + "." + str.tostring(dayofmonth(_t), "00") + " " +
      str.tostring(hour(_t), "00") + ":" + str.tostring(minute(_t), "00") + ":" + str.tostring(second(_t), "00")
```

To get the time and value, I would simply use `var` variables. Update them when it is a new day or if there is a new high.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

f_timeToString(_t) =>
  str.tostring(year(_t), "0000") + "." + str.tostring(month(_t), "00") + "." + str.tostring(dayofmonth(_t), "00") + " " +
  str.tostring(hour(_t), "00") + ":" + str.tostring(minute(_t), "00") + ":" + str.tostring(second(_t), "00")

var int daily_high_time = na
var int prev_daily_high_time = na
var float daily_high = na
var float prev_daily_high = na

is_new_day = ta.change(time("D"))

prev_daily_high_time := is_new_day ? daily_high_time : prev_daily_high_time
prev_daily_high := is_new_day ? daily_high : prev_daily_high
daily_high_time := is_new_day ? time : (high > daily_high) ? time : daily_high_time
daily_high := is_new_day ? high : (high > daily_high) ? high : daily_high

if (is_new_day)
    s = "Daily High: " + str.tostring(prev_daily_high) + "\nTime:\n" + f_timeToString(prev_daily_high_time)
    label.new(prev_daily_high_time, prev_daily_high, s, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

bgcolor(is_new_day ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How would i modify it to also mark the low? I tried changing high to low but the time and placement was wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: You also need to change the condition to something like `low > daily_low`. If you still cannot make it work, please ask a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out and manged to hook it up to my script, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you'll have to execute the script below on a lower timeframe chart
I found this script which is very similar to what you're trying to do
https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-know-the-date-when-a-highest-value-was-found

```
//@version=5
indicator('Day of High', '', true)
len = input(100)
hi = ta.highest(len)
hiOffset = -ta.highestbars(len)
TimeHighDay = time[hiOffset]
plotchar(TimeHighDay, 'TimeHighDay', '', location.top)
plotchar(dayofmonth, 'dayofmonth', '', location.top)
plot(hi)
```